# ILMerged Classes Not Visible To Resharper

Tags: resharper, ilmerge

I have ILMerged some assemblies.  For example:

- Foo.Bar
- Bar.Foo
- Foo.Baz

Into one assembly. For example:

- FooBarBaz.Merged

And it works.  That is, when I reference **FooBarBaz.Merged** and use something like **Foo.Bar.MyClass** in code it compiles just fine.

However Resharper (v5) does not work.  Usages of any type from the merged assembly are bloody red.  What's worse, I get no intellisense for these types either.  Basically this assembly cannot coexist with Resharper.

I wonder if there's some ILMerge param that can cure this.  ILMerge documentation is pretty well hidden, but I found [this](http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:YMJrEhjWGl8J:moq.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Tools/ILMerge.doc+ilmerge+allowmultiple&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a).  I have hacked at various switches...to no avail.

Alternately, is there some Resharper setting I can change.  I really prefer not to have to do this because this is an OSS project.

Comment: There is a an issue for this over at Jetbrains if anyone is interested in voting for support:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-192616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this.  It's a bug in Resharper, I beleive.  However it's not a bug that matters to me.

It seems that Resharper has trouble seeing types of an ILMerged assembly if the project that references that assembly is inside a solution that contains some of the assemblies that got merged.  This is not a case that I care about.

I learned this from [this thread](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5253869#5253869).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants this fixed please go here to vote up support for ILMerged assemblies in R#: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-192616